# Swift Default parameter uses cached value

Tags: swift

I have this method which takes in a flag, and based on which it updates the UI.

```
func foo(flag: Bool = Reachability.isReachable) {
    if (flag) {
        // Show an alert
    } else {
        // Do nothing
    }
}
```

Boolean which is used a default parameter is actually the Reachability's reachable.

Once network connection is turned off, expected value for flag is `false`, but its always `true`. If I check it directly without using a default parameter like `if Reachability.reachable` then it shows the alert.

Is it wrong to use a default parameter which dynamically changes ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to find some official documentation but I can't. Swift default parameter values are bound statically not dynamically. See this post

https://airspeedvelocity.net/2014/06/12/default-parameters-in-swift-are-statically-bound/

EDIT:

Well I'm wrong, looks like it is dynamic. You can test it with this playground:

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import Cocoa

func myFunction(date: Date = Date()) {
    print("Using date \(date)")
}

myFunction()
sleep(3)
myFunction()
```

You'll see the date changes after waiting 3 seconds, so it's making a new `Date` on the second call... Maybe there's a bug in your reachability code?